# remove labels from plots using ChemoSpec

Tags: r, plot, spectrogram

I am using ChemoSpec for plotting spectroscopy data, but i don't want to label all my curves. How can i remove labels in plot ?

```
plotSpectra(spectrasVISNIR, 
        main = "soil spectras", 
        which = 1:264, 
        offset = 0.0, 
        yrange  = c(0, 0.9),
        amplify = 1
        )
```

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

To hide all the labels, just set `lab.pos` to a value outside the x-range of your data.

To my knowledge, there isn't any finer control for hiding certain labels, etc. without digging into the structure of the *Spectra* object. If you want to only show certain labels, you could set the name attributes to `NULL` for the hidden labels; however, that's pretty inelegant.